# How Can I create an image of my Linux install to an external drive formatted with exFAT?

Tags: exfat

I have a 500 Gig external USB drive formatted as exFAT. I can not create an image from my 12.04 install to this drive with ReDo backup (I found out it lacks support for exFAT) . Note the image will be over 5 GIG so FAT32 is not an option for the external drive. 
Is there another free program I can use to make an image? (Gui would be best)
Note I was able to add exfat support to 12.04 and can see the drive and add files manually as well as delete them. Thanks for any advise. 
Please delete this post, I am new to linux  and since I can not make an image I will not be using it anynore. I do not comprehend the answer but I appreciate the lone respone

Comment: You might also need [exfat-utils](http://namhuy.net/872/how-to-enable-exfat-on-ubuntu.html) package for older version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Supported features for gParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted#Supported_features) (also **[see this](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php)**), the program [gParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) should be able to Copy your exFAT Partition from your source disk to a different disk.

There are lots of "HowTo's", tutorials and videos on how to run this task of which I provide you with some links, some of them are dated on 2006, which means that the process can be done since then, so please don't complain about "how old are the tutorials".

1. http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/move/move.htm
2. http://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/03/copy-partitions-with-gparted/
3. http://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/gparted

and a Video:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BEZJmKqxYs

You may experience some kind of issue when running the process from LiveCD/USB, so you may consider installing gParted in a physical install of Ubuntu and connect the hard disk drives in the proper connections (PATA/SATA/USB) in order to avoid these problems.

I have read somewhere in the net that Clonezilla also allow you to cloning exFAT partitions but I haven't tested exFAT cloning myself, however, Clonezilla is my favorite when cloning partitions/disks.

If you need further support don't hesitate to drop a comment or a new question about gParted and the copy function.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to add support for your exfat partition by installing package exfat-fuse .  If doing `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse` doesn't work, then you might try first adding a repository as in the instructions at http://softwaroid.com/2011/12/20/how-to-solve-the-unknown-filesystem-type-exfat-problem/ .